# Migration Java web application from Tomcat 6 to JBoss EAP 6

Tags: java, migration, tomcat6, jboss6.x

I have a Java Web Application that running on Tomcat 6 with Java 6, Hibernate 2.2, Oracle. I need migrate it to JBoss EAP 6.x. Please help with the steps that need to be done for that migration ... any direction would help!

Comment: Good news! [JBoss EAP 6](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) uses *JBoss Web (based on Tomcat 6.0)*. Just make sure you ***read*** [Class Loading and Modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html), the *modular classloader* allows you to do things you can't do with vanilla Tomcat.

Comment: http://www.jboss.org/migration/

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).  It doesn't really have any rules for your use case, but may have in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your prompt responses.

Deploying war to JBoss wouldn't work:

- DataSource needs to be defined (either from EAP management console or manually) in standalone.xml file that kind of replaces context.xml that I had in Tomcat.
- JBoss EAP comes with Hibernate 3 or 4 that are not backward compatible with Hibernate 2. Deploying hibernate2.jar file via EAP management console resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy your .war file on JBoss server.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP 6 is based on WildFly 8. Therefore you may often use the community guides for Wilfly 8 or JBoss AS 7.

Besides that, JBoss / Red Hat has quite a lot of migration materials.
For instance, this [EAP 6.4 migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Migration_Guide/index.html) or a knowledge base on customer portal. Since You're interested in EAP, I assume you have Red Hat subscription.